# Add results from two Sql querys in one query?

Tags: mysql

Basically I have 2 Queries which are returning the required Results

But I need to add these two results in a "sub-query"(if thats even a term).

Heres the two queries that work:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM AccountTransactions
INNER JOIN AccountTransactionDocuments
ON AccountTransactions.AccountTransactionDocumentId = AccountTransactionDocuments.Id
where AccountTransactionDocuments.Date > '{Start}' and AccountTransactionDocuments.Date < '{End}' and AccountTransactions.Name = 'Cash Payment';
```

And

```
SELECT SUM(case when TenderedAmount > 0 then TenderedAmount else 0 end) AS TenderedAmount FROM Payments
where Payments.Date > '{Start}' and Payments.Date < '{End}' and  Payments.Name = 'Cash' ;
```

And here is a copy of what I tried. I didn't know what to put in the final FROM

```
SELECT
       (SELECT SUM(case when TenderedAmount > 0 then TenderedAmount else 0 end) AS TenderedAmount FROM Payments
where Payments.Date > '{Start}' and Payments.Date < '{End}' and  Payments.Name = 'Cash')
       +
       (SELECT SUM(Amount) AS Amount FROM AccountTransactions
INNER JOIN AccountTransactionDocuments
ON AccountTransactions.AccountTransactionDocumentId = AccountTransactionDocuments.Id
where AccountTransactionDocuments.Date > '{Start}' and AccountTransactionDocuments.Date < '{End}' and AccountTransactions.Name = 'Cash Payment') 
AS Cash Drawer 
FROM Payments;
```

Any Ideas??
Or is this even possible?

EDIT:
It was the space in the AS *Cash Drawer* that caused syntax error.
Also removed the last FROM and it works perfect thanks

Comment: Is a [UNION query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your top and bottom queries work, you slam them together with a union all and then sum those 2 results. Ive change the tendered amount to amount in the bottom query so it ties together.

```
    SELECT 
    SUM(amount)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        SUM(Amount) AS amount
    FROM
        AccountTransactions
    INNER JOIN AccountTransactionDocuments ON AccountTransactions.AccountTransactionDocumentId = AccountTransactionDocuments.Id
    WHERE
        AccountTransactionDocuments.Date > '{Start}'
            AND AccountTransactionDocuments.Date < '{End}'
            AND AccountTransactions.Name = 'Cash Payment' 
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        SUM(CASE
                WHEN TenderedAmount > 0 THEN TenderedAmount
                ELSE 0
            END) AS amount
    FROM    
        Payments
    WHERE
        Payments.Date > '{Start}'
            AND Payments.Date < '{End}'
            AND Payments.Name = 'Cash') AS amounts
```

Comment: Works Perfect Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Remove `FROM Payments` from the outer query. That will cause it to perform the two subqueries for each row in the `Payments` table, and return as many copies of the sum as there are rows in that table.